# Execute 'step 1' inside 'step 2' - cypress+cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I faced with many similar pieces of code in my steps, re-using steps inside 'bigger' steps can solve the problem. Is it possible to run step 1 inside step 2?

```
And('My Step 1', () => {
  some code;
});

And('My Step 2', () => {
  can I execute 'My Step 1' here?
  code;
});
```

Comment: Nested steps are now supported in cypress-cucmber-preprocessor https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/cucumber-basics.md#nested-steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the steps in the command file and then call them in your tests.
Your commands will look something like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("Step1", function () {
  Do stuff here
});
```

And then in your tests you can reuse those commands like this:

```
it('My Step 2', () => {
  cy.Step1();
  code;
});
```

Remember to import the command file in your index.js

Comment: thanks, looks like it's the best available solution.